# How to create a feature for uploading files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I'm not really used to ask some questions. But it's gonna 4 days now, and I'm still stuck with this issue.

I would like to create a feature, using Visual Studio 2010, which allows me to upload and replace some files into a Sharepoint 2010 web site. Visual studio and C# are brand new for me, but with our good friend Google, I can handle it.

I can make a feature for changing the title of my website for example. But I don't really know how to do for uploading and replace some files (like a .css or a .js for example). I don't even know where to start and what I should looking for.

Do you guys have a clue to help me out?

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Replacing files can mean a lot of different things (including some *evil* things to do :))

Comment: For example, in a css I have got a the border of a div in blue, and I have to change it to green. So I made a new css files and I want to replace the old one with the new one. And it's the same with my js files

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you exactly are trying to do? I can provide you with code to upload files within SharePoint, but if I see what files you are trying to upload I am wondering how you want to use them.

If you are trying to add css or js files to use them in your own webparts, you should add a mapped folder for "Layouts" and put those files in that folder. There are a lot of different possibilities with SharePoint, so maybe to start you should check out some hands on tutorials to create a feature, custom webparts, ... and a lot of your questions will be answered in those tutorials.

Good luck with it!

Comment: Actually in the web site there are some js with jquery code for some animation and some stylesheet to have some personnal design. For example I have got a http://myWebSite/Style Library/css/all.css and I want to change some border color. And for the js, there is an animation with an opacity and i want to do a slidedown. That I wanted to do is a feature, which, when it's activated, you ve got the new color and the new animation. I was thinking about replacing the files. I don't know if it's the best way to do it. I gonna looking for more tutorials to see how I can do it.

Comment: If you want a new design it is recommended that you create your own masterpage, that is based on the default one. In this masterpage you can then link the needed css and js files. Then when you activate your feature you can then automatically apply your own masterpage, which applies the new design. In this way, if there is something wrong with the masterpage, you can always go back to the default one.